# How To Filter foreign key in seralizers django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My question is how can filter foreign key in serializer?

first, let's look at my code then I will explain you everything in detail!

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.BigIntegerField()
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sprint(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.BigIntegerField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Backlog(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    ......
    as_a = models.ForeignKey(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_created = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user", "program", "date_created",)

    def get_date_created(self, instance):
        return timesince(instance.date_created)

class SprintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_created = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sprint
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user", "date_created", "project",)

    def get_date_created(self, instance):
        return timesince(instance.date_created)

class BacklogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_created = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    project = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Backlog
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user", "date_created", "project",)

    def get_date_created(self, instance):
        return timesince(instance.date_created)
```

**views.py**

```
class BacklogAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BacklogSerializer

    def get_project_or_404(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Project, pk=self.kwargs.get("uuid"))

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user.id, project=self.get_project_or_404())
        
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = Backlog.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id, project=self.get_project_or_404())
        return query_set
```

now my page looks like this:

[image]

but as you can see in the sprint tab there are 2 choices one is assigned to this project and 2nd is assigned to other project

my question is how can I show only this project choices!

it is showing me all sprint choices I want to show only this particular project choices here

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prefetch` in your project query.

```
 queryset = Project.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'spring', queryset=Spring.objects.filter(project='your_project_id')))
```